# Clone to computer hangs

Tags: github

Im using clone to computer with the git hub app for mac.

It starts the download and hangs at the same % every time and just stops.

I deleted the app and reinstalled it. Same issue, I have no trouble downloading other repositories.

What could be the issue?

Comment: How long are you waiting to determine that it is hanging? And are you downloading to a local drive or a network mount? Have you tried with any other git software tools?

Comment: What happens if you try to clone from the command line?

Comment: Ive tried numours times and waited over an hour, its being downloaded to a local drive.

Comment: How can I clone it from command line?

Comment: @panthro Check this out: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository#Cloning-an-Existing-Repository